# Is it possible to search an entire SQL table in the database for any instances of a lower case letter? (SQL Server 2019)

Tags: sql

Only upper case letters are allowed in the database and I would like to make sure no lower case letters were saved.

Thank you for any help!

I have not been able to locate any SQL statements to search an entire table in a database.

Comment: It honestly shouldn't matter, since the default collation is not case sensitive for compares and you can always use `UPPER()` when running a `SELECT` query to only return uppper-case values. In other words, the reason you don't see any other examples of this is because it's an unreasonable thing to try to do.

Comment: I can't go in to too many details because the database contains confidential information.  The data is shared via exports and views in to the database.  It is critical the data is stored with all upper case letters or data will be rejected by partner agencies.

Comment: If case makes a difference then use a case-senstiive collation. Then `WHERE value <> UPPER(value)` will tell you all values that are not valid.

Comment: "...and I would like to make sure no lower case letters were saved." -- If you want to be sure don't search; add a data integrity constraint.

Answer (score 0):

This script will give you all rows of tables that contains strings with some lowerchars inside:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(max) = N'';
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + N'SELECT ''' + C.TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + C.TABLE_NAME + ''' AS TABLE_FULL_NAME, * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(C.TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(C.TABLE_NAME) + ' WHERE ' +
       STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + ' <> UPPER(' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + ') COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CS_AI', ' OR ') + ';'
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  AS C
       JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS T
          ON C.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME AND C.TABLE_SCHEMA = T.TABLE_SCHEMA
WHERE  TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' 
       AND DATA_TYPE LIKE '%char%'
GROUP  BY C.TABLE_SCHEMA, C.TABLE_NAME;
EXEC (@SQL);
```